# ¿Como mostrar tabla html dependiendo de los privilegios de cada usuario?

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, ajax

lo que quiero hacer con PHP es que dependiendo del tipo de usuario se visualice la tabla, ya que, cada usuario tienen diferentes permisos,

en la imagen muestro a lo que me quiero explicar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la consulta del inicio de sesion la obtnego de la clase Usuario del metodo login()

```
public function login(){
$usuario = $this->usuario;
$pass = $this->password;

$sql = "SELECT Usuario, Contraseña, IdGrupo as idgrupo,Pass,Nombre FROM USUARIOS WHERE Usuario = '$usuario' AND IdGrupo IN (1, 2, 3)";
$login = $this->db->query($sql);
if ($login && $login->num_rows == 1) {
$usuario = $login->fetch_object();

if ($password == $usuario->Pass) {
$login = $usuario;
}
    }

return $login;
}
```

no se la manera de realizarlo espero y me puedan ayudar o dar a algún consejo un saludo ante mano

Comment: Pues con un condicional seria la manera, pero no explicas de donde salen esos datos de la tabla, si son resultado de una consulta o estan hardcodeados.

Comment: hola @masterguru mi pregunta lo eliminare para dar mas explicacion y asi poder mostrar de donde obtengo mis tablas y como esta conformando los tipos de usuarios excelente dia

Comment: no hace falta que la borres. La puedes editar las veces que quieras. Pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para modificarla.

Comment: @masterguru coloque la consulta cuando se iniciasesion, estoy abierto en cual quier cambio a mi codigo, o si requiere algo mas

Comment: Bueno, vamos por partes porque sigo sin tenerlo claro: 1) ¿Los datos de la tabla dependen del IdGrupo del usuario?  2) La implementación de login que haces es muy peligrosa pues es susceptible de muchos errores e inyeccion SQL (me falta ver lo que es $this->usuario, aunque ese es otro tema más extenso a tratar después en todo caso) 3) Ese `return $login;` donde va a parar despues? ¿a una variable de sesión? 4) ¿como generas la tabla a visualizar? ¿donde está su código para poderte indicar que hacer allí?